# Stop wheel scrolling on certain point using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I need to be able to stop wheel scrolling on certain point. This is simlified version of my script

```
window.addEventListener( 'wheel', function(e) {
    var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log( 'scroll_top', scroll_top );
    if( scroll_top > 100 ) {
        console.log( 'PREVENTING SCROLL' );
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
}, { passive:false })
```

The problem is, the window scrolls way past 100px. I need it to stop right after ( 5-10px adter is still fine, but now it is even over 300px past). Is there any way to do it? Baysically I need the page scroll untill I get to slider, then stop the verticall scrolling and replace it with scxrolling the slider (I have this part sorted) and once the slider is finished, I need to continue scrolling (this part is also done).